# jQuery keyup only keys that affects textarea content

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I detect if the value of a textarea changes using jQuery? I'm currently using keyup() but this triggers every key stroke of course, I dont want my code to run if it's an arrow key that was pressed or any other key that doesn't have an impact on the value of the textarea.

Take a look:

```
$('textarea').keyup(function() {
     if (content was changed)
         // Do something
});
```

I hope you understand. How can I do this the best way? I don't want to compare the current value to an old value to check for changes, I hope that's not the only way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By all means the easiest way is to store old values to data and do the check every `keyup`. The solution is quite short and will work in any case. No need to reinvent the wheel.

```
$("textarea").data("oldValue", function() {
    return this.value;
}).keyup(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (this.value !== $this.data("oldValue")) {
        // Do something

        $this.data("oldValue", this.value);
    }
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/vvbSj/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('textarea').blur(function() {
  //This will be invoked when the focus is removed
});

$('textarea').change(function() {
  //Same as the blur
});
```

Is this what you want